# how do i print output in one digit after decimal in jsp output from database sever in java

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

**i am dividing the number & want output only with one decimal like 4.1 or 4.2**

```
"SELECT  count(*)/6 as s from t1 ";   

<td class = "inp"><% out.print(rs.getDouble("s")); %></td>
```

**Please help, I am new to jsp**

Comment: The method printf(String, double) is undefined for the type JspWriter

Answer (score 0):

use `String.format` and `%.1f` format (1 digit after decimal point):

```
<td class = "inp"><% out.print(String.format("%.1f", rs.getDouble("s")))); %></td>
```

Comment: The method printf(String, double) is undefined for the type JspWriter

Comment: The method printf(String, double) is undefined for the type JspWriter

Comment: @pankaj Updated to use String.format